# Pyspark - how to group by and create a key value pair column

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data similar to the below one:

```
Col1,col2,col3
a,1,#
b,2,$
c,3,%
```

I need to create a new column with col2 as key and col3 as value, similar to below:

```
Col1,col2,col3,col4
a,1,#,{1:#}
b,2,$,{2:$}
c,3,%,{4:%}
```

How can I achieve this using pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

Try `format_string`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('col4', F.format_string('{%d:%s}', 'col2', 'col3'))

df2.show()
+----+----+----+-----+
|Col1|col2|col3| col4|
+----+----+----+-----+
|   a|   1|   #|{1:#}|
|   b|   2|   $|{2:$}|
|   c|   3|   %|{3:%}|
+----+----+----+-----+
```

If you want a key-value relationship, maps might be more appropriate:

```
df2 = df.withColumn('col4', F.create_map('col2', 'col3'))

df2.show()
+----+----+----+--------+
|Col1|col2|col3|    col4|
+----+----+----+--------+
|   a|   1|   #|[1 -> #]|
|   b|   2|   $|[2 -> $]|
|   c|   3|   %|[3 -> %]|
+----+----+----+--------+
```

You can also convert the map to a JSON string, similar to your expected output:

```
df2 = df.withColumn('col4', F.to_json(F.create_map('col2', 'col3')))

df2.show()
+----+----+----+---------+
|Col1|col2|col3|     col4|
+----+----+----+---------+
|   a|   1|   #|{"1":"#"}|
|   b|   2|   $|{"2":"$"}|
|   c|   3|   %|{"3":"%"}|
+----+----+----+---------+
```